# Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm in Google Earth Engine for parameter optimization

Tags: google-earth-engine, parameters, optimization

I have managed to successfully run the model below in Google earth engine, however the parameters `α` and `β` are unknown coefficients that need to be determined through optimization based on the conditions below:

```
var Q = ee.Image(-1) // Value to use when none of the conditions match 
  .where(
    evaluate('(Vo) <= ((Sa) - P)'),
    0
  )
  .where(
    evaluate('((Sa) - P) < (Vo) < (Sa)'),
    evaluate('(((P - (Sa) + (Vo)) * (P - (Sa) + (2*(Vo)))) / (P - (Sa) + (2*(Vo)) + S))')
  )

  .where(
    evaluate('(Sa) <= (Vo) <= ((Sa) + S)'),
    evaluate('( P * ( 1 - ( ( ( ( (Sa) + (S) - (Vo) ) **2) ) / ( (P * ( (Sa) + (S) - (Vo))) + ( S * (S + (Vo)) ) ) ) ) )')
  )
```

To compute the initial soil moisture `Vo` and the threshold soil moisture, `Sa` the following equations were used:

where `Vo = α√(P5*S)`

and `Sa = βS`

`P5` is the 5-day antecedent rainfall and `P` is the precipitation for the day.

Is there a way to achieve this in GEE?